# Should a React component prop be required when the data is fetched from the backend API?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-proptypes

Like any other app, for rendering a specific section of my React app, I'm expecting to receive a list of items from my backend API. I've created a typical Card component to display the data of each item. This Card component has a parent component which is common for all of the items. It would be something like this:

```
<ParentComponent>
 <CardItem headline image/>
</ParentComponent>
```

The props `headline`and `image` are required, so in theory, I should always receive them from my API. Therefore, I've set these props as required in my component:

```
CardItem.propTypes = {
  headline: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  image: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}
```

As we all know, as our app grows, it can always happen that for some specific reason, even though these props are required, I could receive an undefined value. For this reason, I like doing my components bulletproof and, even though those props are required, I always do a conditional rendering for avoiding the app to break:

```
{headline && (
  <Component/>
)}
```

For other components I just check at the very top if the prop exists, otherwise, I return null:

```js
if (!itemId) return null
```

While unit testing my components, I make sure this behavior is tested so that if I receive any undefined vale from my API, the app doesn't break. I've realized that Jest keeps warning me because of this:

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop headline is marked as
>   required in CardItem, but its value is undefined.

It makes me wonder if my approach is not the right one so here my doubts:

1. Is my approach correct and there is a way to avoid these warnings on Jest?
2. Should the props of a component never be required when the data is received from an API?
3. Instead of checking in the component children, the parent component should not render the children if the props don't exist? - This one feels like it is not the correct one at all but I'm adding it just in case it is a valid approach.

Please don't let your response be influenced by the fact that I'm checking props like `headline` or `image`, I know for something like this I can always render conditionally. Think more of the case of an `itemId` or similar which are props 100% required for the correct rendering/behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In the components, there is an option of **defaultProps**.

In the case, that you **don't receive the props** from the API. You can **provide your own defaultProps** to the component.

if you are using the **functional component**, It would be something like this **outside the component**

```
CardItem.defaultProps = {
    headline: "YOUR_DEFAULT_VALUE",
    image: "YOUR_DEFAULT_VALUE",
}
```

and if you are using a **class component**, it would be something like this **inside the class**

```
static defaultProps = {
   headline: "YOUR_DEFAULT_VALUE",
   image: "YOUR_DEFAULT_VALUE",
}
```

and by doing this, you don't need to validate the props

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't set a default prop for `itemId`, that's my point

Answer (score 0):

See there can be multiple scenarios,
1. Children totally depends on parent for data. In this case parent should not render child if props are undefined/null. i.e rendering of children should be bulletproof.
2. If children is independent in sense that it makes sense if parent somehow doesn't provide props to it and still it can work with some default values then you can render the children. But here comes the approach you wanna take, as mentioned in above answer there's defaultProps. but if you don't wanna go with it, then you can try something like this,

```
interface ComponentProps {
prop1?: string;
prop2?: number;
}

export const Component:React.FC<ComponentProps>=({prop1='',prop2=0})=>{
return(
// logic goes here
)};
```

Now when you test this component Jest will not complain and you can test the values easily.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So for a prop which is `itemId` for example, you suggest setting for example an empty string as default value? is that a good practice?

Comment: It again depends on the business requirements. But yes, providing default values to props as a fallback values is good if it suits our requirements. Otherwise as I mentioned, parent will not render child if we cannot show component with default values.